# Find $\,f(x,y)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R^2}$, such that$\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=xy,\hspace{0.3cm}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x+y$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

$f(x,y)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R^2}$ such taht

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=xy,\hspace{0.3cm}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x+y$$

Find $f(x,y)$.

I tried to integrate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=xy$ with respect to $x$ and then differentiate with respect to $y$,but this becomes difficult to solve.Please help to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such function. The partials are smooth, hence the function is smooth. Then the second derivative should be symmetric everywhere, but the above shows that this can only hold at $x=1$.

Comment: @copper.hat thank you so much.

Comment: @copper.hat:  how's your boy doing with D68?

Comment: @RobertLewis: Much better! Thanks for asking! It took us by surprise, thankfully hospitalization wasn't necessary.

Comment: @copper.hat:  so glad to hear that news!  Truly a blessing!  Best thoughts and wishes for a complete and speedy recovery!  Warm Regards.

Comment: @RobertLewis: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=xy\quad\Longrightarrow\quad f=\frac{1}{2}x^2y+g(y),
$$
and hence
$$
\frac{1}{2}x^2+g'(y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x+y,
$$
which is not possible.

Hence, no such $f$ exists!

EDIT. As suggested by copper.hat, another way to attack this question is to use the fact that, if $f\in C^2$, then $(f_x)_y=(f_y)_x$. So here $f_x=xy$, $f_y=x+y$,  and
$$
(f_x)_y=x\ne 1=(f_y)_x.
$$

Comment: Or you could note that the 2nd partials are not symmetric.

Answer (score 3):

This problem closely resembles the process of trying to solve "exact" ode's.

First, integrate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ with respect to x. The constant of integration will be a function of y.

Then integrate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ with respect to y. The constant of integration will be a function of x.

Then put them together in a consistent way.

$$f(x,y)= \int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\ dx = \int xy\ dx=\frac{x^2y}{2}+g(y)$$ and,
$$f(x,y)= \int \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\ dy = \int x+y\ dy=xy+\frac{y^2}{2}+h(x)$$

The reason that you are having difficulty is that this is inconsistent. This can be verified using Euler's Criteria: does $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y}=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y \partial x}$ ? If not, then such a function will not exist. It is better to apply this test first; here it makes the process of trying to find a potential function unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to be the bearer of evil tidings, but there is no function $f(x, y)$ such that

$f_x = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = xy \tag {1}$

and

$f_y = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x + y; \tag{2}$

for (1) and (2) affirm the existence of a scalar function $f(x, y)$ such that

$\nabla f= (xy, x + y), \tag{3}$

i.e., $(xy, x + y)$ is the gradient of $f$; but we have

$\nabla \times \nabla f = 0 \tag{4}$

for any gradient $\nabla f$; on the other hand, we compute (using the two-dimensional version of $\nabla \times$)

$\nabla \times (xy, x + y) = D_x(x + y) - D_y(xy) = 1 - x \ne 0; \tag{5}$

thus, $(xy, x + y)$ is not the gradient of anything; the equation(s) have no solution.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***